# can't find the error in this mergesort program in c..always shows segmentation fault

Tags: c, sorting, merge, segmentation-fault

I cannot find the error in this Mergesort program in C. 
It always shows segmentation fault.

This is my code by the way for Mergesort:

I think the problem may be here:

```
void merge(int *a, int i, int mid, int n) {
    int l, m, k, b[10];

    l = i;
    m = mid + 1;
    k = 0;

    while (l <= mid && m <= n) {
        if (a[l] > a[m])
            b[k++] = a[l++];

        if (a[m] > a[l])
            b[k++] = a[m++];
    }

    while (l <= mid)
        b[k++] = a[l++];

    while (m <= n)
        b[k++] = a[m++];

    for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
        a[i++] = b[k];

    return ;
}
```

Comment: your second while loop has no curly braces

Comment: recompile your code with the `-ggdb3` flag in `gcc` and run it in a debugger like `gdb`. You can then `backtrace` to the seg fault's location in source code.

Comment: Just because you think the problem might be in some vague location within part of your code, does not mean you should only post that part. If the problem is not there, then only posting it is of no use at all. Posting incomplete code and expecting people to guess what the rest of it does is not exactly polite. You should post the minimal amount of code needed to compile the program. This is not that.

Comment: @ja08prat there is just one statement in while loop so i didn"t feel the need to....

Comment: @underscore_d  i was posting the whole code but id didn't let me as the code part was too much it showed an the reason i posted this part because it has the maximum chances of error as the remaining part is calling the merge function and dividing the array into smaller arrays

Comment: @Amit777: did one of the answers allow you to fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Towards the end of your function (among other places..):

```
for(k=0;k<n;k++)   // k = [0 -> n)
    a[i++]=b[k];   // but b is declared as int b[10], this is surely not right.
```

The above loop implies that you are expecting `b` to hold exactly `n` elements at some point.  Why is 'b' not sized properly?

Comment: but b[10] was just to declare the array so that i can add the sorted elements into it and if b[10] is used this just means that the array size is 10 but i am no bothered about the size as if terminating my loop before that ,i.e. upto n the last index of my parent array a[ ]...........am i wrong here ?

Comment: 10 is just not big enough. to hold n elements if n > 10.  It doesn't matter what you intended it for, it's just too small.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the `mid` argument seems to be the index to the last element in the left half and `n` the index to the last element in the right half. This is inconsistent with the common practice in C, `i` is the index to the left half, `mid` should be the index to the first element of the right half and `n` should be the index to the first element beyond the right half. This way the array lengths are easy to compute by subtracting the initial index from the index beyond the last element.
- `b` is allocated locally as an array of size `10`.  This is incorrect if the size of of the chunk to be merged is larger than 10.  You could either allocate an array of `(n - i)` elements with `malloc()` or define a local array `int b[n - i];` if the size of the array to be sorted is not too large (less than 1 million entries for a modern 64-bit environment).
- `l` is a poor choice for the name of a local variable: it is graphically too close to `1`, creating potential errors and confusion.
- the tests in the main merge loop are both redundant and incomplete: you do not handle the case where the element in the left half is equal to that in the right half.
- the last loop, copying the merged data back into the source array is flawed: it should read:

  ```
  for (k = 0; k < n - i; k++)
      a[i++] = b[k];
  ```

Here is a corrected version for moderately small arrays:

```
void merge(int *a, int start, int mid, int end) {
    int i, j, k, b[end - start];

    i = start;
    j = mid;
    k = 0;

    while (i < mid && j < n) {
        if (a[i] <= a[j])
            b[k++] = a[i++];
        else
            b[k++] = a[j++];
    }
    while (i < mid) {
        b[k++] = a[i++];
    }
    while (j < n) {
        b[k++] = a[j++];
    }
    for (i = start, k = 0; i < end; i++, k++) {
        a[i] = b[k];
    }
}

void mersort(int *a, int length) {
    if (length > 1) 
        int mid = length / 2;
        mergesort(a, mid);
        mergesort(a + mid, length - mid);
        merge(a, 0, mid, length);
    }
}
```